# Java Hibernate - Query with a list as join

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate

In java code I generate thousands of ids, next I need to get those ids in the postgresql database, so far I have this (used createNativeQuery as pseudocode):

```
            Query q = em.createNativeQuery(
                    "select * from mytable where id in (:ids)"
            ).setParameter("ids", listofIds);
```

I'm afraid about the IN clause, I fear that there might be a huge number of values, is there another better way to perform this?

Comment: Either build a sub-query which fetches the ids, or load your records in multiple batches to reduce the amount of data you process with each query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can scale to quite large lists by doing

`select * from mytable where id = any(cast(:ids as bigint[]))`

but you have to format the list of ids as a string in Java first, like

`ids = "{" + String.join(",", listofIds) + "}";`

Still, there will always be some threshold where the list is just too large for Java or Postgresql to handle, so you'll need to break it up into batches if you want to support arbitrarily large lists.